# Grouping data for multiple variables by a single variable

Tags: r, group-by

In the following dataset, I want to do two things

```
pt_id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Tobacco <- c("once","twice","never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once","Twice","Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, "Never")
Alcohol <- c("twice", "once",NA, NA, "never", NA, NA, "Once", NA, "Quit", "Twice", NA, "Once", NA, NA, "Never", "Never")
PA <- c("once",NA,"never", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,"Once",NA,"Quit","Once",NA,NA,"Never", NA, NA)
mydata <- data.frame(pt_id, Tobacco, Alcohol, PA)
mydata
```

1. Count the number of rows per patient that are not NA for each variable (Tobacco, alcohol and PA) grouped by patient ID.

I used the following code to get my output but I can do it only for one variable at a time.

```
mydata_tob <- mydata %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Tobacco)) %>% 
  group_by(pt_id) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   pt_id [3]
  pt_id     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     3
2     3     4
3     4     2
```

But this is very time-consuming for me as I have many many variables in my original dataset. I want a similar kind of output for all the variables in one go.

2. My end result is I want to calculate the percentage of pt_id with more than 1 entry for each variable.
   I created the following function (only for tobacco) to be able to do so

```
gt1_prop <- function(n) {
  gt1_len <- length(mydata_tob$n[mydata_tob$n > 1])
  len_tot <- length(mydata_tob$n)
  gt1_prop <- (gt1_len/ len_tot)*100
  return(gt1_prop)
}
```

Again I want to code in a way that I get the proportion for each variable (Tobacco, Alcohol and PA) in the dataset.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To count number of non-NA values for each `pt_id` you can use `across`.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~sum(!is.na(.)))) -> result
result

#  pt_id Tobacco Alcohol    PA
#  <dbl>   <int>   <int> <int>
#1     1       3       3     2
#2     2       0       1     0
#3     3       4       3     3
#4     4       2       2     1
```

For 2nd step to calculate the percentage you can do :

```
result %>%
  summarise(across(Tobacco:PA, ~mean(. > 1) * 100))

#  Tobacco Alcohol    PA
#    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1    0.75    0.75   0.5
```

Comment: When I tried to run this code on my original dataset and initially I got this error      
```.                                                                                                                          Warning messages:
1: In TOBACCO_USER:SOCIALIZATION_FREQ :
  numerical expression has 5 elements: only the first used
3: In get(object, envir = currentEnv, inherits = TRUE) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```   However when I tried doing it again, I didn't get this error. Any idea why I got the error the first time?

Comment: Not sure it might be because some packages might be clashing with `dplyr` overwriting `summarise` function.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
aggregate(.~ pt_id, mydata, FUN = function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = NULL)
```

-output

```
#   pt_id Tobacco Alcohol PA
#1     1       3       3  2
#2     2       0       1  0
#3     3       4       3  3
#4     4       2       2  1
```

---

Or more compactly with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
rowsum(+(!is.na(mydata[-1])), mydata$pt_id)
#  Tobacco Alcohol PA
#1       3       3  2
#2       0       1  0
#3       4       3  3
#4       2       2  1
```

---

If we need the percentages

```
colMeans(rowsum(+(!is.na(mydata[-1])), mydata$pt_id) > 1)
#Tobacco Alcohol      PA 
#   0.75    0.75    0.50
```